# Substituir toda as letras de uma String por asteriscos

Tags: java

Não estou conseguindo substituir todas as letras da palavra por asterisco, só algumas estão sendo substituídas. Como faço para que todas sejam substituídas?

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String conversor = null;

System.out.println("Digite a palavra a ser criptografada");
String palavra = sc.nextLine();

for(int i=0;i<palavra.length();i++){
    conversor = palavra.replace(palavra.substring(i), "*");
    System.out.println(conversor);
}

System.out.println(conversor);
sc.close();
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Precisa imprimir todas essas vezes? Por que? Ou se fez isso pra verificar os passos e só precisa dos asteriscos impressos no final no lugar do texto digitado? E por que precisa disso? Parece algo sem muito sentido ou uma coisa simples demais até para se enrolar, tem alguma coisa que não sabemos sobre o problema? Algum requisito não mostrado na pergunta?

Comment: Coloquei para imprimir todas as vezes apenas pra saber o que estava acontecendo dentro do for. Estou treinando criptografia e me passaram esse exercício.

Comment: Quero que toda a String fique com asterisco. Palavra Criptografada = ****** ************

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o método `replaceAll` passando um regex para substituir todas as letras exceto o espaço:

```
"Palavra Criptografada".replaceAll("[^ ]", "*");
```

Pelo seu exemplo nos comentários, é isso que quer, mas se precisar alterar caracteres específicos, basta adaptar a regex

Comment: Era isso mesmo que eu queria !! Obrigado rapaz.

Comment: Fabio, escolha a resposta dele como a melhor.

Answer (score 3):

Eu também sou fã de regex, mas para este caso não vejo grandes necessidades. Também devo discordar um pouco da [resposta do Costamilam](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/439000/64969) porque ele substitui coisas que não são letras por letras, já que mantém apenas o espaço (a expressão `[^ ]` indica qualquer coisa que não seja o caracter espaço ) como caracter original.

Para substituir apenas as letras, vou identificá-las usando [`Character.isLetter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter-char-). Também vou trabalhar inicialmente com um vetor de caracteres para, no final, converter de volta para string. Vou pegar os caracteres usando [`String.toCharArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray--) e construir a nova string usando o construtor [`String(char[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-char:A-).

```java
String palavra = ...; // recebe a palavra, advinda de onde é adequado
char[] caracteres = palavra.toCharArray();

for (int i = 0; i < caracteres.length; i++) {
  if (Character.isLetter(caracteres[i])) {
    caracteres[i] = '*';
  }
}
String palavraModificada = new String(caracteres);

// faz o que deseja com a palavra modificada
```